# How do you find generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the generating function (within a choice of sign) for:
$$c_{n+1} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k c_{n-k},\;\;\;n=1,2,3,4,\dots\\c_0=1, \;c_1=3$$

How would you use the generating functions here from the sequence type?
Not just regular formula.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nx^n$$ be the ordinary generating function for the sequence. Then the standard formula for the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two summations yields

$$\big(g(x)\big)^2=\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nx^n\right)^2=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^nc_kc_{n-k}\right)x^n=\frac12\sum_{n\ge 0}c_{n+1}x^n\;,$$

and multiplication by $2x$ gives us

$$2x\big(g(x)\big)^2=x\sum_{n\ge 0}c_{n+1}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 1}c_nx^n=g(x)-c_0\;.$$

This is a quadratic in $g(x)$, so it can straightforwardly be solved for $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The above gives the generating function as

$$g(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt(1-8x)}{4x}$$
but this is not correct as it does not generate the correct sequence.

The correct sequence is $$1,3,12,66,408,2712,\dots$$
and this is generated by
$$GF=\frac{1-\sqrt(1-8x-8x^2)}{4x}$$

For a corrected proof, see this 2019 post: [Generating Function For Catalan Numbers Type Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138866/generating-function-for-catalan-numbers-type-sequence)